# Android login website with Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

When I goto [this URL](https://www.cgv.vn/vn/theaters/showtimes/) and get urlLogin.
After which, I'm trying to log into urlLogin.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.cgv.vn/vn/theaters/showtimes/").get();

            Element element = doc.getElementById("top_register");

            //Get url login
            String urlLogin = element.childNode(0).attr("href");

            Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            Document document = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                    .data("login[username]", "ABC")
                    .data("login[password]", "ABC")
                    .data("cookieexists", "false")
                    .data("form_key", "WrToMuENMoOq8ZA3")
                    .data("form_key_test", "WrToMuENMoOq8ZA3")
                    .data("send", "")
                    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                    .post();

            //a page you want to load after login
            String url = "https://www.cgv.vn/vn/customer/account/";

            Document fpl = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .timeout(5000)
                    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                    .get();
           String body = fpl.body().toString();

            Log.e("test", body);
```

Unfortunately, this simply returns the same page in a not-logged-in state. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Some points you may check:

#### 1) Login manually

Try to login manually with your favorite browser and spy its exchanges with the Dev Toolbar or a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Once done, reproduce the same exchanges in your code with Jsoup.

#### 2) Form fields `form_key` and `form_key_test`

Ensure these fields aren't generated randomly by the server. You may need to extract their value from the document and not hard code their respective values.

See the two lines below:

```
.data("form_key", "WrToMuENMoOq8ZA3") // randomly generated ?
.data("form_key_test", "WrToMuENMoOq8ZA3") // randomly generated ?
```

#### 3) Missing cookies

Did you check that the following statements doesn't produce new cookies needed for later fetching `https://www.cgv.vn/vn/customer/account/`.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                .data("login[username]", "ABC")
                .data("login[password]", "ABC")
                .data("cookieexists", "false")
                .data("form_key", "WrToMuENMoOq8ZA3")
                .data("form_key_test", "WrToMuENMoOq8ZA3")
                .data("send", "")
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                .post();
```