# How to use jsoup to login in android

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I want to scrap the title after login.

This is my code

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("url")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .timeout(10000)
                    .execute();

Document doc = loginForm.parse();
String ltValue = doc.select("input[name=urlCache]")
                    .attr("value");

String spa = "";
String stepUp = "";
String facilitate = "";

doc = Jsoup.connect("url")
           .data("urlCache", ltValue)
           .data("spa", "")
           .data("stepUp", "false")
           .data("facilitatedUrl", "")
           .data("userId", username)
           .data("password", password)
           .data("remember", "on")
           .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
           .data("loginbtn", "Log In")
           .post();

title = doc.title();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android login website with Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017647/android-login-website-with-jsoup)

Comment: And what is the question?